# Azure function javax.xml.bind.JAXBException

Tags: java, maven, azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I'm trying to run this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-java-maven) function following the instruction provided by Microsoft. I'm currently running java version 10.0.1 and I get the `javax.xml.bind.jaxbexception`. I know that it references a github [article](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6477) that is supposed to provide me with a workaround but I'm still getting the same error. So far I've tried updating the dependencies in my `pom.xml` and I've attempted to add the command line argument `--add-modules java.xml.bind`. How do I add this command line argument when execvuting `mvn clean package`? If it helps I'm running on macOS High Sierra.

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
        <artifactId>azure-functions-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-beta-3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```